# Ionic Vue 3 on subdomain on Firebase Hosting not finding index.html

Tags: firebase, vue.js, ionic-framework, firebase-hosting

Using Ionic and Vue 3 I wrote an app that works well. I'm now using the same code to put the app functionality onto my website - portal subdomain. I have a second subdomain (www) pointing at a separate html only site in the same hosting area.

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) -> site1
portal.example.com -> site2

This all works fine. If I go to **portal.example.com** I get the correct homepage with various options which I click on and I go to the relevant vue page such as **portal.example.com/contacts**. I can then click on a contact and it shows me the correct page - **portal.example.com/contacts/ba76ea50-e1b6-414b**

This is where the problem lies. If I copy\paste that url (**portal.example.com/contacts/ba76ea50-e1b6-414b**) into another browser window I get the Firebase Page not Found page:
[image]

What this is saying to me is that the index.html page that the Vue 3 app is mounted on is not being initialised when copy pasting and going directly to the url. I have no idea how to tell the Vue 3 app how to do that. I guess it should be in the portal.example.com firebase.json file:

```
    "hosting": [{
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites":[{
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
    }]
  }]
```

Am I looking at the right place or am I completely going in the wrong direction? This is important because the specific URLs are emailed to users so they can click and see the correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is firebase.json related. As there are multiple sites in the hosting you have a firebase.json for each site plus one at a root level. The root level firebase.json maps subdomain to the site. I needed to add the rewrites section to the root firebase.json as well.

```
   {
    "hosting": [{
      "target": "www",
      "public": "public-area/dist",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ]
    },
  {
      "target": "portal",
      "public": "portal-area/dist",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [                      <-- added
        {                                <-- added
          "source": "**",                <-- added
          "destination": "/index.html"   <-- added
        }                                <-- added
      ]                                  <-- added
  }]
  }
```